# Word order for asking a question

Tags: word-order, questions

1. When will the contract be awarded?
2. when the contract will be awarded?

At times, I am confused over the word order of a sentence. In this example, I am asking a question.

How do I determine the word order and which is a better sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1: When will the contract be awarded? is the correct order. When asking a question like this, the word "will" will almost always come after who, what, where, when, why, or how (if the word "will" is in the sentence). For example, you would say, "Where will the event take place", "Who will host the meeting today?", "What will we be doing later?", "Why will he be coming over later?", and "When will school start?"