# Which is correct? I would like to know when the delivery day is? or I would like to know when is the delivery day?

Tags: grammaticality, word-order, questions

Which is correct?

**I would like to know when the delivery day is?**

or

**I would like to know when is the delivery day?**

Comment: There have been many questions on this topic, for example https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/226151/word-order-for-asking-a-question

Answer (score 2):

**I would like to know when the delivery day is** is not a question, so it doesn't have a question mark.

**When is the delivery day?** is a question, and **I'd like to know: when is the delivery day?** *includes* that question, but notice the punctuation. *Without* punctuation it is ungrammatical.

We would usually ask, **When is the delivery day?** or, less brusquely, **Can/could you tell me when the delivery day is?** or perhaps just, **Do you know when it will be delivered?**